# Sorting time column with am/pm in yii2

Tags: yii2

In my table `tasks` I have 2 column `task_startdate`, `task_starttime`. The `task_starttime` is stored in format G:i A (01:30 AM) format. I want to sort the `task_starttime`. Sorting directly with `task_strttime` is not helping. So I tried to convert the datetime to unixtimestamp.

In my model I've added -

```
public function getTaskunixtime()
    {
        $starttime = $this->task_startdate. ' '.$this->task_starttime;
        return strtotime($starttime);
        //return strtotime("2009-11-03 11:24:00PM"); 

    }
```

And View I can see it by -

```
[
                        'label' => 'Starttime',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'attribute' => 'starttime',
                        'value' => function($data){
                            return $data->getTaskunixtime();
                        },
                        //'taskunixtime',
                        
                    ],
```

[image]

I don't really want to show the starttime column to the user. Also I'm unable to sort it with this function.

In the dataprovider, I tried below -

```
$dataProviderTasks = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Tasks::find()
            
            ->where(['task_startdate' => $model->dr_date, 'task_assignedto'=> $model->dr_empid, 'task_report' => 'Daily Routine']),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 100,
            ],
            
            //'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['taskunixtime' => SORT_ASC]],
            
        ]);


        $dataProviderTasks->sort->defaultOrder = [ 'taskunixtime' => SORT_ASC];
```

This dataprovider is not in a searchmodel. It's within a controller action.

Please help.

Comment: You want to always sort it by `taskunixtime`? You could just alter the query ... `Tasks::find()->where([...])->orderBy('taskunixtime ASC')`, this would force the table to be **always** sorted by `taskunixtime`. Im assuming thats what you want, because you dont want to use a search model?

Comment: Yes. I want this only. But adding `->orderBy('taskunixtime ASC')` doesn't help because this is not a table name. I'm getting error - `Unknown column 'taskunixtime' in 'order clause'`.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to restructure your database and just use one column (e.g. `task_start`) and not 2 (`task_startdate` and `task_starttime`). Whats the reason you have those 2 columns separated even though its one? Is this really necessary/required to have 2 columns? Its the same as you would use 1 integer and some kind of decimal number and not allow any value higher than or equal to 1. They obviously belong together, the same as in your case the date with time, so why dont use a datetime?